# how to find the path of cookbook created

Tags: git, chef-infra

I am creating cookbooks from git bash through this command `knife cookbook create name`.

And the cookbook is getting created.
But i want to know the folder where these cookbooks are being created.
Please help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

That command will generate use `./cookbooks/name` unless your `knife.rb` overrides the cookbook and/or chef repo paths. Also worth mentioning it is deprecated in favor of the `chef generate` suite of generator tools.